# get user info like name , photo and profile picture after using facebook login without graph API

Tags: android, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am using face login SDK in my app

> com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)

after integrating Facebook login API in my app I get the success response in a object `LoginResult` like this

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "permitted attributes " +
                            loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

but I was wondering is there any way to get user information like

> userPhoto , user name , email

I have seen Facebook API doc and it seems I need to use Graph API for this . is there any other way around to get this done with Facebook login SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can in facebook login SdK 4+

you will get a Profile object for the current logged in user .

In Your onSuccess callback method call the static method `getCurrentProfile()`

```
private final String id;
private final String firstName;
private final String middleName;
private final String lastName;
private final String name;
private final Uri linkUri;
```

these are member variables for a current logged in user . and for profile picture there is a method `getProfilePictureUri(
            int width,
            int height)`
 for more details see the official [DOCS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/facebook/com/facebook/profile.html/)